# Is possible to persist data in the .net assembly Metadata or Header?

Tags: .net, assemblies, signature, strongname

I want to implement a custom assembly signature mechanism just like Strong Name,
then develop a program to write the signature info in the assembly Metadata,In the assembly of internal read and verification of the signature is correct.
Is possible to do this?

Comment: Don't be ridiculous. An assembly is a file. You should know by now that .NET cannot read or write files!

Comment: Sure, why would you want to? :)

Comment: Why? I simulated sn.exe,it happend after compile completed

Comment: Why would you want to simulate sn.exe? Just learning, or is there a real purpose here?

Comment: I am trying to implement a custom Digital Signature of assembly,and want to save signature info to dll or exe file

Comment: Ok, if the .NET Digital Signature isn't good enough for you, but you still can't write to assemblies, since they are files.

Comment: Also, files don't exist.

Comment: They never have, either.

Comment: Truer words have never been spoken.  Or typed.  Or thought.

Comment: What I mean is that assemblies file have been generated,use other software modify dll binary file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly possible. You should add a custom attribute for the assembly. To do so, make an entry in the CustomAttribute table, which is defined in section 22.10 of [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

Comment: Yes, but he can't write it to the _file_.

Comment: @John: I really cannot understand whether you are trying to be humurous in claiming that .NET cannot write to files. Of course there is plenty of API to write to files in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET assemblies are regular Windows .exe and .dll files. So instead of writing .NET metadata, you can add resources to the file - using WIN32 functions like UpdateResource.